# Asset file 'project.assets.json' has no target for 'net6.0/win -x64' on wapproj project

Tags: windows, visual-studio, msbuild, msix

I have a C# Winforms app + C++ DLL + wapproj project for .MSIX file, I wanted to publish my app on x64 mode but when I want to generate packages. I have the error:

> Asset file 'project.assets.json' has no target for 'net6.0/win -x64'.
> Check that the restore ran and you included 'net6.0' in
> TargetFrameworks for your project. You may also need to include
> 'win-x64' in your project's RuntimeIdentifiers.

It says it was on my package project.

Tried to add `<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>`, delete bin and obj folder. Nothing worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I resolved my self by checking all .csproj, .vcxproj, .wapproj and adding `<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>` and `<RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>`.

After deleting all bin and obj folder, recompiling and publishing, it resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can check the publish setting like this:
[image]